# How to convert any global variable into a promise?

Tags: javascript, svelte

**Hello**, i'm just authenticating a user through firebase auth i want to add user data into a global variable (account) then i can add at into svelte store here is my code.

```
import { firebaseConfig } from "../firebase";
import { user } from "../Stores";
import { link } from "svelte-spa-router";
import {
    getAuth,
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    GoogleAuthProvider,
    signInWithPopup,
} from "firebase/auth";
let email;
let password;
let account;
const HandleSubmition = async () => {
    const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        getAuth(),
        email,
        password
    );
    email = "";
    password = "";
    demo(userCredential);
};
async function demo(Authuser) {
    const auth = await Authuser;
    return auth;
}
const handleGoogleSignup = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    signInWithPopup(getAuth(), provider).then((userCredential) => {
        account = userCredential.user;
    });
};
account = demo();
account.then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

but when i console.log(accout) it giving undefined i want it to return promise which resolve the i can add it to store

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Function
`async function demo(Authuser) { const auth = await Authuser; return auth; }`
Here `account = demo();` you are calling the function demo without argements, which leads to throw undefined error.